# Sumif worksheet function referencing another workbook

Tags: excel-formula

I want to put a sumif formula into my worksheet but need to refer to another workbook but am using variables. What am I doing wrong?

I've defined matcher as a variable.

```
Dim column1 As Variant
Dim Column2 As Variant

column1 = Workbooks("Week 36 Headcount summary Perm.xlsx").Sheets("Page1_1").Range("B:B")
Column2 = Workbooks("Week 36 Headcount summary Perm.xlsx").Sheets("Page1_1").Range("D:D")

Cells(7, matcher) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(column1, A7, Column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF requires Ranges, not arrays, so you need to use:

```
Dim column1 As Range
Dim Column2 As Range

Set column1 = Workbooks("Week 36 Headcount summary Perm.xlsx").Sheets("Page1_1").Range("B:B")
Set Column2 = Workbooks("Week 36 Headcount summary Perm.xlsx").Sheets("Page1_1").Range("D:D")

Cells(7, matcher) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(column1, Range("A7"), Column2)
```

I guessed that A7 was supposed to be a range, not the name of a variable.

Comment: Thanks Rory, That's working great now. Can I ask for my own learning, why do you need to use set before the variable definition. It doesn't work if you dont and I don't understand the significance of that word yet

Comment: You have to use `Set` when assigning an Object type (e.g. `Range`, `Workbook`, `Worksheet`) rather than a data type (e.g. `Long`, `Integer`, `String`), to a variable.

Comment: That's great, really appreciate your help with this. I've spent hours trying to figure it out since I'm still learning. i should have signed up to this website this morning and been able to communicate with kind folk like you quicker! Cheers

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to mark this as the answer. ;)